# Onsen UI database connection

Tags: angularjs, database, onsen-ui

I am using [Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/) to develop a cross platform mobile app. I am new to Onsen and AngularJS for that matter.

How do I connect to a Database to pull information into the app using AngularJS and Onsen? Is there a example somewhere I can reference? I have searched online but cant find a good example.

I have the basic UI built using Monaca but now I need to make a connection to the database to check logins and read and write data to and from the app.

I am having a difficult time understanding how the 2 work together.

Answer (score 1):

Try below link.

[Onsen and angularJs Datbase](http://monaca.mobi/en/blog/lets-make-a-sample-app-to-connect-with-the-backend-using-angularjs/)

I hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks Priyanka. Its helped me understand how to work with the Monaca Backend better and how to read/write data from it. But I will be using AWS as my Database solution. How do I connect to that please?